# SELinux permissions for LogRotate and Apache

Tags: linux, security, selinux, logrotate

With the directory structure:

```
/www/live/website1/app/
/www/live/website1/files/
/www/live/website1/logs/
```

Where Apache needs at least the following access:

```
app: read-only access, but read-write is fine (files already chmod 0644)
files: read-write access
logs: read-write access
```

Where the following two rules have been setup via:

```
/usr/sbin/semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/www/live/.*/.*";
/usr/sbin/semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_log_t "/www/live/.*/logs(/.*)?";

/sbin/restorecon -vr "/www";
```

Which are applied, and seem to be working fine... however LogRotate isn't happy.

The LogRotate config is currently:

```
/www/live/*/logs/*access_log /www/live/*/logs/*access_log_443 {
    weekly
    rotate 52
    missingok
    notifempty
    nodateext
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /usr/sbin/apachectl graceful > /dev/null
    endscript
}
```

However, this seems to be blocked by SELinux, with entries appearing in the audit.log when its trying to hit the inode related to the `/www/live` folder (262146 in the example below)... as its presumably trying to list the folders in /www/live/.

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1396579563.324:316060): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=12336 comm="logrotate" name="live" dev=dm-0 ino=262146 scontext=system_u:system_r:logrotate_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1396579563.324:316060): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7fff2cef68b0 a1=90800 a2=7fff2cef6b5a a3=8 items=0 ppid=12334 pid=12336 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=35531 comm="logrotate" exe="/usr/sbin/logrotate" subj=system_u:system_r:logrotate_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
```

So what context should I set this parent directory?

```
/usr/sbin/semanage fcontext -a -t default_t "/www(/.*)";
```

Where I know `default_t` doesn't work, nor does `var_t`... and for reference I don't really care what can see these folders, as they are already chmod 0755.

---

And for bonus points... is there an easy way to see the full list of permissions a program has? I know LogRotate must be able to access `httpd_log_t` and `var_log_t`.

The annoying thing is that running LogRotate manually seems to bypass these restrictions, as I assume that its inheriting the users permissions (unlike when it runs via cron).

Comment: Show us a relevant audit.log entry.

Comment: Good point, has been added @Iain

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not confirmed if this is the right answer yet...

```
/usr/sbin/semanage fcontext -a -t sysfs_t "/www(/.*)";
/usr/sbin/semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/www/live/.*/.*";
/usr/sbin/semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_log_t "/www/live/.*/logs(/.*)?";
/sbin/restorecon -vr "/www";
```

There the `sysfs_t` is the important bit.

I can find the domains that LogRotate can use with:

```
sesearch -s logrotate_t -SA
```

Doing a quick search for the "read" (not just "open") permission for "dir":

```
sesearch -s logrotate_t -SA -c dir -p read | sort
```

Then scanning though the list, I would say that `sysfs_t` is the most appropriate.

---

A problem I did find is that if I run `/usr/sbin/logrotate` myself, it inherits the root account context:

```
id -Z
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

So it automatically gets "unconfined" access (i.e. full access)... so to test, I found that using the following, while not perfect, did kind of work:

```
sandbox /usr/sbin/logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf
```

I also found out about `newrole` and `runcon`, both of which need to be installed separately on a RedHat/CentOS system via:

```
yum install policycoreutils-newrole

newrole -r system_r -t logrotate_t
runcon -r system_r -t logrotate_t /usr/sbin/logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf
```

But both of these were giving me permission denied errors (probably due to the transition not being allowed):

http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/How_does_a_process_get_into_a_certain_context

---

Something else I found useful:

```
yum install setools-console

seinfo -usystem_u -x
seinfo -rsystem_r -x
seinfo -tlogrotate_t -x

seinfo -tsysfs_t -x
```

---

And to check the list of rules I've created on the system:

```
cat /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local
```

---

For more information on SELinux, I found these 17 tutorials very helpful:

http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials

---

Personally I have found all these programs very inconsistent, and can understand why most people just disable SELinux by default... e.g.

- You can't have a space after the seinfo options -u/r/t
- You need to install extra packages to get `seinfo` and `newrole`
- You can't easily run a program manually under a given context (for testing purposes).
- The `audit.log` file uses timestamps, so instead try `ausearch -m avc --start today`.
- No naming convention with the many programs used (e.g. `matchpathcon`).
- I wouldn't say the output (or operation) of `audit2allow` was obvious.

Which is a shame, as it seems to be a a very powerful system overall.